# Different results for same command run from system() vs mac terminal?

Tags: r

I would have expected this R code

```
system("chromedriver --version") 

[1] "ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877})"
```

to have returned exactly the same result as running the same code from the terminal, i.e.

```sh
chromedriver --version

ChromeDriver 2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189)
```

but as we can see the results are not the same.

Why does running the same code using `system()` vs mac terminal yield a different result?

Comment: Check `Sys.getenv("PATH")` vs `echo $PATH`.

Comment: @r2evans they are different where I would have thought they’d be the same since (I though) they’re accessing the same global environment variable?